# how to stop my code from looping at the end?

Tags: c#, dice

**i'm new at coding C# pls help me fix this simple dice game, it keeps on looping at the end of the game**
** apparently how i think is that in the end of this code something makes the NO commend on looping and getting re runed**

```
using System;

namespace first_game
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userName;
            userName = Console.ReadLine();

            #region
            {
                int userPoint = 0;
                int cpuPoint = 0;
                int pDice;
                bool closeApp;
                while (true)
                {
                    while (cpuPoint < 10 && userPoint < 10)
                    {
                        Random rd = new Random();
                        pDice = rd.Next(1, 6);
                        #endregion
                        int P2Dice;
                        Random scondRd = new Random();

                        P2Dice = scondRd.Next(1, 6);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
                        Console.Write("playe dice:");
                        Console.WriteLine(pDice);
                        Console.Write("CPU dice:");
                        Console.WriteLine(P2Dice);
                        Console.ReadLine();

                        if (pDice > P2Dice)
                        {
                            userPoint = userPoint + 1;
                        }
                        else if (pDice < P2Dice)
                        {
                            cpuPoint = cpuPoint + 1;
                        }
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine(userName);
                        Console.Write("player point:");
                        Console.WriteLine(userPoint);

                        Console.Write("CPU point:");
                        Console.Write(cpuPoint);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    if (userPoint == 10)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------\nYOU WIN!!!");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------\nYOU lost!!! LOL");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
   
                    Console.WriteLine("wanna continue?\n press Y for yes   press N for NO");
                    ConsoleKeyInfo sw;
                    sw = Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    if (sw.Key == ConsoleKey.Y)
                    {
                         userPoint = 0;
                         cpuPoint = 0;
                        continue;
                    }

                    else if (sw.Key == ConsoleKey.N)
                    {
                    
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR!");
                }  

            } 
                
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (true) {...}` is **infinite** loop, it runs forever; to stop it looping you should `break` it somewhere: `if (some_condition) break;`

Comment: There's a reason why _Apple's_ previous head office address was "One Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA".  We've all written at least one (though usually not that obvious).  You have two nested `while` loops, you need to make sure that you break out of both of them

Comment: One other (unrelated) comment.  You create your instance of `Random` within the loop.  You only need one instance; create it as you enter your program and reuse it.  If you create two instances in quick succession, you may end up with identical sequences of numbers.  And, why do you declare a `#region` in your code, and why does it span scopes the way it does?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the wrong idea about `continue`. A while loop always (given a true condition) reruns if it reaches the end, a continue just starts the next iteration early.

```
else if (sw.Key == ConsoleKey.N) { } 
else Console.WriteLine("ERROR!");
```

This is where you should exit the loop, for example using a `break`

```
else if (sw.Key == ConsoleKey.N) { 
  break;
} else Console.WriteLine("ERROR!");
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `break` to exit the `while` loop:

```
if (userPoint == 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------\nYOU WIN!!!");
    break;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------\nYOU lost!!! LOL");
    break;
}
```

Then add this after the `while` loop, so that the console doesn't close:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```